# Where to perform service registration in unicorn?

Tags: ruby, rack, unicorn, apache-zookeeper, service-discovery

I'm building a service discovery library for our rack applications to use. It's based on [ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/), and leverages ZooKeeper's ephemeral znodes so that when a service loses its connection to ZooKeeper (crash, reboot, network partition), its entry in the service registry automatically disappears.

Most of our rack applications are managed by [unicorn.rb](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/).

I'm not sure where to perform service registration. I can't have every worker process that unicorn spawns handling service registration. So it seems I need some horrible IPC amongst the workers to elect one responsible for service registration; or I need unicorn elect and notify a worker; or I need to do service registration in unicorn.rb.

The last option seems the least ugly. But where do I do that? In after_fork?